# Why oracle table indexed but still do full table scan?

Tags: database, performance, oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization

I have a table 'MSATTRIBUTE' with 3000K rows. I used the following query to retrieve data, this query has different execution plan with same DB data but in different env. in one env, it appears full scan so the query is very slow, but in another env it all used index scan it's quite good, everybody who knows why it have full table scan in one env because I built index for them, how do I let become index scan just like what I tested in env 1. how I can improve this query?

Comment: Isn't `3000K == 3M` ? ;)

Comment: Was the index was added recently (it's unclear to me), and if so have you gathered statistics since then? You can check the `last_analyzed` column of `all_tables` and `all_indexes`; for a new index the latter might be null. The optimizer might not consider using the index if that is the case.

Comment: Is the index present in all environments? Are you using the same software version in every environment? What are your environments?

Comment: the index was built when creating table, so it was not added recently. the data is same, I use imp/exp import from one database(env) and export to another env, the only difference is one env is oracle 11g R1 which used full table scan, the another db which used index scan is 11g R2, but I think this small version difference would not affect execution plan.

Comment: @Kur.C On the other hand there could be a code difference between R1 and R2 that does explain the difference in execution plans entirely.

Comment: Where is the query and index details?? I see them in the edit history and without that this question never makes sense w.r.t. APC answer

Answer (score 4):

without understanding way more than I care to know about your data model and you business it's hard to give concrete positive advice.  But here are some notes about your indexing strategy and why I would guess the optimizer is not using the indxes you have.

In the sub-query the access path to REDLINE_MSATTRIBUTE drives from three columns:

- CLASS
- OBJECT_ID
- CHANGE_RELEASE_DATE.

CLASS is not indexed.  but that is presumably not very selective.  OBJECT_ID
is the leading column of a compound index but the other columns are irrelevant the sub-query.

But the biggest problem is CHANGE_RELEASE_DATE.  This is not indexed at all.  Which is bad news, as your one primary key look up produces a date which is then compared with CHANGE_RELEASE_DATE.  If a column is not indexed teh database has to read the table to get its values.

The main query drives off

- ATTID
- CHANGE_ID
- OBJECT_ID (again)
- CHANGE_RELEASE_DATE (again)
- CLASS (again)
- OLD_VALUE

ATTID is indexed but how sleective is that index?  The optimizer probably doesn't think it's very selective.  ATTID is also in a compound index with CHANGE_ID and OLD_VALUE but none of them are the leading columns, so that's not very useful.  And we've discussed CLASS, CHANGE_RELEASE_DATE and OBJECT_ID already.

The optimizer will only choose to use an index if it is cheaper (fewer reads) than a table scan.  This usually means WHERE clause criteria need to map to the *leading* (i.e. leftmost) columns of an index.  This could be the case with OBJECT_ID and ATTID in the sub-query except that

1. The execution plan would have to do an INDEX SKIP SCAN because REDLINE_MSATTRIBUTE_INDEX1 has CHANGE_ID between the two columns
2. The database has to go to the table anyway to get the CLASS and the CHANGE_RELEASE_DATE.

So, you might get some improvement by building an index on `(CHANGE_RELEASE_DATE, CLASS, OBJECT_ID, ATTID)`.  But as I said upfront, without knowing more about your situation these are just ill-informed guesses.

Comment: thanks very much your detail info, yes, OBJECT_ID will extremely minimize the data, then remain columns have almost equal selective. will OBJECT_ID have unique index be better? even this is not good strategy, but is was not slow to a few minutes, but, in one env, it used full table scan that waste a few minutes to execute, do you have idea why two env have different execution plan?

Answer (score 3):

If the rows are in a different order in the two tables then the indexes in the two systems can have different clustering factors, and hence difference estimated costs for index access. Check the table and index statistics, including the clustering factor, to see if there are significant differences.

Also, do either of the systems' explain plans mention dynamic sampling?

Comment: I use imp/exp import from one database(env) and export to another env, so the row has same order. checked two env both index states are valid. the dynamic SQL is also same, used full table scan.

Comment: As you can see the where clause have 4 conditions, two column of them are indexed, but two: CHANGE_RELEASE_DATE(date type) and class(number) are not indexed, will this cause one env uses full table scan?

Comment: @Kur.C: exp/imp does not preserve the row order.

Comment: @Kur.C Check the index "statistics", not "states". If the clustering factor is different then the rows may be differently ordered, though it would also depend on how many blocks the two versions of the table use.

Comment: Thanks, I will check the index "statistics" to see is it different

Answer (score 1):

when oracle has an index and decides to use/not use it it's might be because 
1) you may have different setting for OPTIMIZER_MODE - make sure it's not on RBO.
2) the data is different - in this case oracle might evaluate the query stats differently. 
3) the data is the same but the stats are not up to date. in this case - gather stats

```
dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('your3000Ktable',cascade=>true);
```

4) there are allot more reasons why oracle will not use the index on one environment, i'll suggest comparing parameters (such as OPTIMIZER_ INDEX_COST_ADJ etc...)

Answer (score 0):

One immediate issue is this piece SELECT RELEASE_DATE FROM CHANGE WHERE ID = 136972355  (This piece of code will run for every row coming back and it doesn't need to... a better way of doing this is using a single cartesian table so it only runs once and returns a static value to compare....

Example 1:

```
Select * From Table1, (Select Sysdate As Compare From Dual) Table2 Where Table1.Date > Table2.Compare.
```

Is always faster than
    Select * from Table1 Where Date > Sysdate --  Sysdate will get called for each row as it is dynamic function based value.  The earlier example will resolve once to a literal and drastically faster.  and i believe this is definitely once piece hurting your query and forcing a table scan.

I also believe this is a more efficient way to execute the query.

```
Select  
            REDLINE_MSATTRIBUTE.ATTID
           ,REDLINE_MSATTRIBUTE.VALUE
  From 
            REDLINE_MSATTRIBUTE
           ,(
                SELECT  ATTID
                        ,CHANGE_ID
                        ,MIN(CHANGE_RELEASE_DATE) RELEASE_DATE
                 FROM   REDLINE_MSATTRIBUTE
                       ,(SELECT RELEASE_DATE FROM CHANGE WHERE ID = 136972355) T_COMPARE                
                WHERE   CLASS             = 9000
                  And   OBJECT_ID           = 32718015
                  And   CHANGE_RELEASE_DATE > T_COMPARE.RELEASE_DATE
                  And   ATTID IN (1564, 1565)
                GROUP 
                   BY   ATTID,
                        CHANGE_ID
            ) T_DYNAMIC
Where         
        REDLINE_MSATTRIBUTE.ATTID = T_DYNAMIC.ATTID   
    And REDLINE_MSATTRIBUTE.CHANGE_ID = T_DYNAMIC.CHANGE_ID
    And REDLINE_MSATTRIBUTE.RELEASE_DATE = T_DYNAMIC.RELEASE_DATE
    And CLASS     = 9000
    And OBJECT_ID = 32718015
    And OLD_VALUE ='Y'
Order 
   By   REDLINE_MSATTRIBUTE.ATTID,
        REDLINE_MSATTRIBUTE.VALUE;
```

Comment: I'm not sure on your assertion(_This piece of code will run for every row coming back_). See the execution plan.

Comment: +1 for @Florian, as these result sets can be cached even when they are correlated.

Comment: as the query runs it has to check for the current state of release date as it could have changed during the course of your query...  depending on your isolation level this could cache or not cache... the cardinal method guarantees running once to get a static value and resolves to a literal and is always faster.... if you test Where date > sysdate on a milliion row table a cartesian method will be 10 to 30% faster...

Comment: if you have isolation level set to committed read there will be extra over head to make sure that the db engine constantly checks the release date to see if it has a new committed value.... thus more overhead ... the cartesian product method guarantees evaluating to a static value once ...  this is also a trick discussed on asktom...

Comment: @Tim There's no need for Oracle to re-check if values have changed.  The way Oracle handles statement level consistency with UNDO, all parts of the query are always guaranteed to return data from the same point in time.  Oracle has no uncommitted read, so you're always paying for that overhead.  [Subquery caching](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51asktom-453438.html) should prevent that subquery from running for each row, although I'm not sure what version it was introduced.

Comment: All i know is that i've been doing bulk data processing on Oracle/DB2 and informix for a long time and in each database engine the cartesian static is at least 10% but typically 30% faster every single time.